# User is receiving badges for review tasks they could not have performed

Tags: bug, review, badges

I have come across a user who seems to have accumulated "Steward" badges at an impossible rate; I believe there must be a bug in the platform.

They received the badge 18 times in the 8 hours and 14 minutes between Jan 29 18:31 and Jan 30 2:45 for reviewing close votes (and twice more for other review tasks). This would correspond to reviewing close votes for 18,000 questions (almost 10% of all the questions in the entire community) in a little over 8 hours, which doesn't seem physically possible. Is this system behavior correct?

Comment: I’ve hidden a discussion about the tone of an earlier version of this question, which linked to a specific user’s profile exhibiting this unexpected system behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a bug, Steward and its related badges were changed on Jan 29 so that they were now awarded for every 1000 reviews done. See [this mother meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360279/263383) for more information.

Comment: The official announcement is in [this Mother Meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues), which was Featured SE-wide from January 28 to March 6 of this year.